# How to return command line result in Racket?

Tags: command-line, scheme, racket

I can issue bash commands with Racket with `(system "some command")` , but the function returns #t instead of the resulting output from the command-line, which it only prints. How can I get the result of the command to be returned with the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `system` procedure sets `stdout` to the value of the paramter `current-output-port`. This means that we can collect everything written to `current-output-port` to a string and return that. The construct `with-output-to-string` sets `current-output-port` to a port that doesn't print anything, but eventually returns whatever written to the port as a string.

```
> (with-output-to-string (lambda () (system "date")))
"Sat Jun 25 12:20:12 CEST 2016\n"
```